# Install new version of sqlite 3.8.4.3 android jelly bean

Tags: android, sqlite

how to install new version of `sqlite version 3.8.4.3`, my sqlite current version is `sqlite 3.7.16` , my device running android jelly bean,

thanks for advice :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by updating a library that is present in the firmware?

Comment: sqlite 3.7.16 has no recursive function, but its available now for new sqlite 3.8.4.3, i'm looking for a way to implement depth first search in sqlite https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html